# printing directly from a php5/javascript webapp

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, printing

i have been searching every where, reading tons of outdated posts that only works with php4, so i'm sorry if you might think from first sight that this is a replicate question.

I've developed a webapp that i need user to be able to print directly to printer without opening a new page, or showing the default browser window.

in other term i want to be able to mimic native print functionality from my webapp.

i understand that php5 is a server side language so it might not be possible to interact to user printers using php so my question is.

is there any software/ small code out there that can expose printers list to be called restfully ?

example a small software that my client will install/run on his computer, this app will then listen to post X.

javascript can call this app using `$.ajax` call, example
**GET REQUEST** : show list of available printers.
**POST REQUEST**: will carry pdf,img,html, text or any format ( i can use php to format the data as required by the app) data and app will print it directly on user default printer/ specific printer stated on the post request

an example of such software is implemented by [ubiq, an amazing data visualization tool that let you install there small app, which allows their webapp to interact with your mysql server by ajax requests](http://ubiq.co/).

so i want same thing but for printer not for mysql server :).

does it exists ? if not what would be a good language to code such mini-server ? anywhere to start ?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: On IE activeX can do this. But I wouldn't touch that with a ten feet pole. Otherwise you should write a browser extension.

Comment: @Mouser thanks for the tip, yet i would rather have a native app regardless of the browser the client is using.

Answer (score 0):

Many HP printers support ePrint, a service so that you can email files to your printer, and they will print without going through the OS or OS printer driver. It can accept HTML, DOC, PDF, XLS, JPG, and maybe a few other formats.

We've built web apps in which the user provides the email address of their printer. Then we generate a PDF, and email the PDF to their printer.

Google also offers CloudPrint, which does give you a RESTful interface to printers, but I'm less clear on how printers are identified and how the user would tell an application what the endpoint for their printer is.

(disclaimer: I work for HP, though I am not associated with the folks who do ePrint or printers.)

Comment: ty for your answer, yet i'm searching for a solution that works on a localhost offline network. infact our printers are hp wireless printers yet ePrint require internet connection which is not available.

Comment: If they are on a local network, you can use port 9100.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are on a local network, but not on the Internet, you can use port 9100, which is the default network port.

Here's a tiny bit of information about writing direct to it: http://danieru.com/2013/06/06/what-is-port-9100-how-to-print-to-it/

The easier approach is to configure CUPS on a Linux box (probably the server), so that you've got a local representation of the printer, and then can send the print job to the printer over the network.

Also, I think the HP printers support Internet Printing Protocol on port 631:
http://www.frankworsley.com/blog/2011/1/23/printing-directly-to-a-network-printer

About 15 years ago, I worked on a project that would receive network print jobs in post-script (which allowed the entire organization to use HP Postscript 5 universal driver), accepting jobs for any printer name...but the printer name would be the IP address of the destination printer. Then we'd query over port 9100 to find the model, use Ghostscript to render the postscript into the appropriate printer language for that model, and then send over 9100. So it's possible to do pretty complex and dynamic stuff, although now 15 years later, I don't remember the exact details.